# Change background color with a variable iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa

I want to change the background color of my label with a variable how can I do that ?

This is my code but I'd like to have a variable instead of 'redColor'

```
[publisherLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: [UIColor redColor] returns a UIColor object, so you can keep a reference to it like `UIColor *red = [UIColor redColor]` and pass that to `setBackgroundColor:`, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable with color from an RGBA value.

```
UIColor *myColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:100.0/255.0 green:101.0/255.0 blue:102.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
```

You can also use HEX if you want:

```
#define HEXCOLOR(c) [UIColor colorWithRed:((c>>24)&0xFF)/255.0 
 green:((c>>16)&0xFF)/255.0 
 blue:((c>>8)&0xFF)/255.0 
 alpha:((c)&0xFF)/255.0];

// usage:
UIColor* c = HEXCOLOR(0xff00ffff);
```