# Color Variables in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, colors

How do I set and reuse a color variable in Obj C? I am trying to set a reusable color value as in this question:

[Change background color with a variable iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032393/change-background-color-with-a-variable-ios)

but am unsuccessful.

```
 UIColor *lightGrayHeader = [UIColor colorWithRed:246/255.f green:239/255.f blue:239/255.f alpha:1.0];

 self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayHeader];
```

Returns an error: "Initializer element is not a compile-time constant."

Thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have defined is a local variable. It is used like this:

```
UIColor *lightGrayHeader = [UIColor colorWithRed:246/255.f green:239/255.f blue:239/255.f alpha:1.0];
self.view.backgroundColor = lightGrayHeader;
```

If you want to use a static method on `UIColor` to fetch a colour, you could do this:

```
@interface UIColor (MyColours)
+ (instancetype)lightGrayHeader;
@end

@implementation UIColor (MyColours)
+ (instancetype)lightGrayHeader {
  return [self  colorWithRed:246/255.f green:239/255.f blue:239/255.f alpha:1.0];
}
@end
```

And then as long as you import the `UIColor (MyColours)` header, you could use:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayHeader];
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you've already created the `lightGrayHeader` color, just use it:

```
UIColor *lightGrayHeader = [UIColor colorWithRed:246/255.f green:239/255.f blue:239/255.f alpha:1.0];
self.view.backgroundColor = lightGrayHeader;
self.otherView.backgroundColor = lightGrayHeader;
...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UIColor *lightGrayHeader = [UIColor colorWithRed:246/255.f green:239/255.f blue:239/255.f alpha:1.0];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayHeader]; // error
```

It's a *variable*, not a method of UIColor:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = lightGrayHeader;
```

Answer (score 1):

It works like this `self.view.backgroundColor = lightGrayHeader;`