# How to use colorLiteral, imageLiteral in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I recently learn to use colorLiteral and imageLiteral in Xcode 11. It works fine in my swift file. How can I use colorLiteral and imageLiteral on Objective C file?

It seems Xcode does not support colorLiteral and imageLiteral for Objective C.

Comment: I would recommend not to use them at all outside playgrounds but I guess this opinion is not so common. If possible, use color assets and load the color by name, or at least create a separate `UIColor` extension with color constants.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. These features are not available in Objective-C, only in Swift.

They are Swift Keywords

Answer (score 2):

With reference

- [How to set image to UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41569581/11077258)
- [Color Variables in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28225244/11077258)

Objective-C does not support `color literal` and `Image literal`. Both introduce in `Swift`, early that

- To use an image in Objective-C

```
UIImageView *imgview = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 400)];
[imgview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImageName"]];
[imgview setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
[self.view addSubview:imgview];
```

- For Color

```
UIColor *lightGrayHeader = [UIColor colorWithRed:246/255.f green:239/255.f blue:239/255.f alpha:1.0];
self.view.backgroundColor = lightGrayHeader;
```

If you want to use a static method on `UIColor` to fetch a `colour`, you could do this:

```
@interface UIColor (MyColours)
+ (instancetype)lightGrayHeader;
@end

@implementation UIColor (MyColours)
+ (instancetype)lightGrayHeader {
  return [self  colorWithRed:246/255.f green:239/255.f blue:239/255.f alpha:1.0];
}
@end

And then as long as you import the UIColor (MyColours) header, you could use:

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayHeader];
```

Comment: As an addition to your answer: to use the colours you have set in the xcassets folder, you can also use `[UIColor colorNamed:@"colorNameHere"]` though only available for iOS 11 and up.

Comment: I know how to use set Color and Image in Objective C. I just want to easily change the value by using colorLiteral and imageLiteral. My workaround is to create a swift file and import it into Objective C.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that that features are not available in Objective-C. 
My workaround is to create a swift file for imageLiteral and colorLiteral and imports them in objective c file.

Utils.swift

```
import UIKit

@objc class Utils: NSObject {



   @objc var textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.5609482021, green: 1, blue: 0.3726723031, alpha: 1)

}
```

Objective C file:

```
Utils * utils = [Utils new];
label.textColor = utils.textColor;
```

That way I can take advantage of colorLiteral feature for Objective-C Project.